# Removing white lines in multirow cells

Tags: tables, multirow

How can one remove the line? Or is there a way to reset doublerulesepcolor?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{hhline}

\usepackage{multirow}


\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{|m{5cm}||m{2cm}|}
\hhline{|-||-|}
Table & \cellcolor{black!10} A\\
\hhline{:=:|>{\doublerulesepcolor{black!10}\arrayrulecolor{black!10}}=>{\doublerulesepcolor{black!  0}\arrayrulecolor{black!100}}|}
\cline{2-2}
\multirow{2}{5cm}{\centering\textbf{Text without a line.}} & 1\\
\hhline{|~||-|}
& 2\\
\hhline{|-||-|}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{hhline}

\usepackage{multirow}


\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{|m{5cm}||m{2cm}|}
\hhline{|-||-|}
Table & \cellcolor{black!10} A\\
\hhline{:=:|>{\doublerulesepcolor{black!10}\arrayrulecolor{black!10}}=>{\doublerulesepcolor{black!  0}\arrayrulecolor{black!100}}|}
\cline{2-2}
\multirow{2}{5cm}{\centering\textbf{Text without a line.}} & 1\\
\noalign{\makeatletter
\global\let\CT@drsc@old\CT@drsc@
\global\let\CT@drsc@\relax}
\hhline{|~||-|}
\noalign{\makeatletter
\global\let\CT@drsc\CT@drsc@old}
& 2\\
\hhline{|-||-|}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I just can't believe it!

Comment: @Bernard you should have more faith:-) As Ulrike says for the simple MWE a simple `\cline` is a better idea, bit perhaps the real document needs hhline so it seemed worth providing for that.

Comment: I was kidding, but really, I'm in awe! I agree it's worth providing this solution.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you using \hhline? With \cline there is no problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table,svgnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{hhline}

\usepackage{multirow}


\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{|m{5cm}||m{2cm}|}
\hhline{|-||-|}
Table & \cellcolor{black!10} A\\
\hhline{:=:|>{\doublerulesepcolor{black!10}\arrayrulecolor{black!10}}=>{\doublerulesepcolor{black!  0}\arrayrulecolor{black!100}}|}
\cline{2-2}
\multirow{2}{5cm}{\centering\textbf{Text without a line.}} & 1\\
\cline{2-2}
%\hhline{|~||-|}
& 2\\
\hhline{|-||-|}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply put `\multirow` *after* `\hhline`, with a negative number of rows?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{hhline}

\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|m{5cm}||m{2cm}|}
  \hhline{|-||-|}
  Table & \cellcolor{black!10} A \\
  \hhline{:=:|>{\doublerulesepcolor{black!10}\arrayrulecolor{black!10}}=>{\doublerulesepcolor{black! 0}\arrayrulecolor{black!100}}|}
  \cline{2-2}
                                                              & 1 \\
  \hhline{|~||-|}
  \multirow{-2}{5cm}{\centering\textbf{Text without a line.}} & 2 \\
  \hhline{|-||-|}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]